# libFuzzer, why only show offset instead of detailed function location

Tags: llvm-clang

I am new for libFuzzer. Right now, I use it to find the potential bug in one library (myLibrary.a). So, I write test_fuzz.cpp file which calls the function LLVMFuzzerTestOneInput().

I compile test_fuzz.cpp with clang++ flags " -fsanitize=address -fsanitize-coverage=trace-pc-guard -g -o2", and linked with libFuzzer.a myLibrary.a to create the executable App.

The myLibrary.a is pre-built with same compiler flags (clang++).

Run the App, it did hit the heap-use-after-free. But, it reported as below. My question is, why it can only reports offset instead of detailed location (like function name, file name and line number)? The myLibrary.a contents many files which locates in different folders(modules), it is not possible to list all the files one by one and build with test.cpp.

It is hard for me to use offset to figure out which part of codes have bug. Anything I miss here? Thanks for any helps.

```
==18728==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free on address 0x60f0000000c0 at pc 0x00000127884c bp 0x7f7db9decd70 sp 0x7f7db9decd68
READ of size 8 at 0x60f0000000c0 thread T8
    #0 0x127884b  (/home/workspace/test_fuzz+0x127884b)
    #1 0x127aad5  (/home/workspace/test_fuzz+0x127aad5)
    #2 0x127acd2  (/home/workspace/test_fuzz+0x127acd2)
    #3 0x127e591  (/home/workspace/test_fuzz+0x127e591)
    #4 0x12633ac  (/home/workspace/test_fuzz+0x12633ac)
    #5 0x121efee  (/home/workspace/test_fuzz+0x121efee)
```

Comment: It is hard for me to use offset and find which codes have bug.

Comment: Figure out the solution. In my case, my linux machine need to set two environment variables to show the codes line numbers in the stack trace.

<1>. export ASAN_SYMBOLIZER_PATH= PATH_TO_YOUR_LLVM_SYMBOLIZER

<2>. export ASAN_OPTIONS=symbolize=1